# What does this bashrc ffmpeg command do?

Tags: ffmpeg

Actually i had added this command in my `bashrc` a while ago, now i don't know what it does. I am a noob in `ffmpeg` so i have all the commands converted to `bashrc` aliases.
Does anyone know what this does?

```
ffmpeg -i "$1" -i "$2" -c:v copy -c:a aac "$3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have that command in my `bashrc` too.

It is used to merge the audio and video into one file. I use it to merge the audio and video from a youtube video downloaded from youtube-dl.

The `$1` gets the video file `$2` get the audio file and `$3` is the name of the output file.

For example-

Let's say you want to merge `audio.mp3`, `video.mp4` into `final.mp4` then the command would look something like-

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac final.mp4
```